# How to insert a break line in LaTeX just like hr tag do in HTML?

Tags: line-breaking

In HTML, I can insert a line below any text using `<hr>` tag.

---

---

---

How can I do same thing it in LaTeX?

Comment: Perhaps `\par\noindent\hrulefill\par`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It works! But if I insert it following `\section{}`, the distance between section and line is too long. Can I set it?

Comment: I added a small negative `\vspace`, and posted as an answer.  Is this better, or do you still not like the space following the section.  Compare to a section without the `\ht` included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possibility, I created a macro `\hr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\hr{\par\vspace{-.5\ht\strutbox}\noindent\hrulefill\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\hr
\lipsum[2]
\hr
\lipsum[3]
\clearpage
\section{header}
\hr
\lipsum[4]
\section{header}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]